# what is the limitation of Libmicrohttpd?

Tags: c++, c, linux, http

I want to develop a http server based on the library Libmicrohttpd.

And I m wondering what is the limitation number of users connecting at the same time that Libmicrohttpd can support.

Comment: Also posted, and answered, at https://superuser.com/questions/1287804/what-is-the-limitation-of-libmicrohttpd

Comment: Read the documentation and see [linux - what is the limitation of Libmicrohttpd? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1287804/what-is-the-limitation-of-libmicrohttpd/1287808#1287808)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on a number of factors:

- As HTTP works on TCP, so you need to figure out how many TCP connections your server would be able to support at one time. I'd suggest to do some benchmarks to get an idea. You may use [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) and/or [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). Or, you may write your own benchmark app using [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).
- The other thing is the number of sockets your OS can support. Depending on the OS, you may need to tweak / tune those values. On Linux, you may use [`ulimit`](http://landoflinux.com/linux_ulimit_command.html) command. And, on Windows, you may need to configure registry values.
- The other important thing is the payload that a connection may bring in and the processing that the server has to do. You need to do benchmarks for some predefined amount of data (say, 64KB, 1MB, etc.). In this context, you might want to process all the data ASAP. Sockets have backlogs with fixed sizes. Those need to be configured also. That means you'd be needing more memory so bigger RAM sizes or some fine-tuning of OS stuff also be there. So, memory here is a bottleneck.
- The connection timeouts are also important but you need to think about that if you want to consider those in your benchmarks or not. Depends on the handling of connections by your server.

You may also take a look at [c10k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) to get a general idea. See [this](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) relevant article too.

These are the things that I could come up with at the moment. I'll update my answer if I find anything else.

Hope this helps!